# Linux : how to prevent user space processes from mapping certain memory range

Tags: linux, memory-management

I am working on a ppc platform, where CONFIG_TASK_SIZE=0xa0000000, which means user space program can map anywhere between 0 and 0xa0000000

Now for some reason, I don't wanna user space processes to use 0x40000000 to 0x80000000.

Does anyone know how to achieve this. Either from kernel or user land.

I have tried reserved-memory in device tree, but that didn't work.

Comment: OK, maybe I was not clear in the first place. Let me explain, in my platform, 0x40000000 to 0x80000000 are peripheral I/O registers. In kernel, I stole that memory and did 1 to 1 mapping so that I can access by physical addresses. By doing that, in user land, I can also access that memory by physical address and I need that. Now I wanna prevent   my user processes from using that part memory for anything else. But I still need to access that memory in user land.

Answer (score 0):

Have the kernel map that range limited to kernel mode access.

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: Map that range of addresses with kernel mode only access. Then they cannot be mapped by the user (user mode) and are unusable in user mode.